# Float as a score in the leaderboard

Tags: objective-c, game-center, leaderboard

I have a leaderboard and in itunes connect I selected "Fixed point - to 2 decimals" for this type of leaderboard.
My score is a float value for example "12,13134". But If I upload the score in the leaderboard, is displayed only "0.12" in the leaderboard.

Why is my score, consisting of a float value not displayed correctly?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are posting a score in the format of a signed 64-bit integer `int64_t`, the value of your float gets truncated to simply 12. Once that score makes it to the leaderboard, it gets formatted as a fixed-point decimal, with the point located between the positions of hundreds and tens:

```
#######.## <<== 64-bit integer
       ^
       |
Fixed point position
```

This produces `0.12` output. Similarly, if your score were 121.3134, the displayed value would have been 1.21; 1213.134 would be displayed as 12.13, and so on.

If you keep your raw score as a float, and format it to 2 decimals in the leaderboard, all you need is to multiply the score by 100.